# Avoiding code duplication with conditional code that uses let bindings

Tags: let-binding, local-variables, conditionals

This is the procedural logic I want to program in Elisp:

```
def my_func():
    v1;
    v2;

    if (some_condition):
        v1 = 2
        v2 = 3
    else:
        v1 = 4
        v2 = 5

    foo(v1)
    bar(v2)
    ... # Possibly many other lines of code.
```

I have this in Elisp:

```lisp
(defun my_func ()
  (if some_condition
      (let ((v1 2)
            (v2 3))
        (foo v1)
        (bar v2))
    (let ((v1 4)
          (v2 4))
      (foo v1) ; This block of code is duplicated and could be very long.
      (bar v2))))
```

What is the Llisp way of programming the logic shown above? That is, I have a few variables at the start of my function that can take some values depending on some condition, then the rest of the function goes on.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: I removed the right paren you had after `some-condition`...

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of providing a more basic version of the answer by @db48x you could do the same thing like this:

```el
(defun my-func ()
  (let (v1 v2)
    (if some-condition
        (setq v1 2 v2 3)
      (setq v1 4 v2 5))
    (foo v1)
    (bar v2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are as many ways of writing this as there are people, but here is how I might do it:

```lisp
(defun my-func ()
  (cl-multiple-value-bind (v1 v2)
      (if some-condition
          (cl-values 2 3)
        (cl-values 4 5))
    (foo v1)
    (bar v2)))
```